# Laravel Create New Project

Tags: laravel

Just started to learn Laravel...

I've created my first project following the instructions:
"laravel new proj1".

Then now I want to create another project, do I need to do the whole 
"laravel new proj2" again?

According to the official documentation, "Once installed, the simple laravel new command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. "

But do I need "a fresh Laravel installation" every time I create a new Laravel project? thanks.

Comment: Yes, for each new project you need to do the same process.

Comment: By "fresh Laravel installation", they simply mean you would have to type `laravel new proj2`.  You do not need to require the laravel builder again with composer, you can use `laravel new ...` over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a template or starterkit of your laravel project. There are different kits available online (with necessary login/authentication setup). It's for sure that you will need to pull out for each new project. You can't use same directory for different project. Hope this makes sense.